# How to Sort an Array by Size (in feet and inches) in Perl?

Tags: perl, sorting

I have a perl array with the following sample values:

```
multiple_sizes[0] = 10' 0" x 14' 0":6342
multiple_sizes[1] = 2' 0" x 3' 0":0
multiple_sizes[2] = 4' 0" x 6' 0":829
multiple_sizes[3] = 6' 0" x 9' 0":2022
multiple_sizes[4] = 8' 0" x 10' 0":3145
multiple_sizes[5] = 9' 0" x 12' 0":4821
```

The object is to sort these values by ascending width.  The problem is that 10' 0" is sorted before 2' 0" and also (not shown), 2' 10'' is sorted before 2' 6''.

Is there a way to have the array sorted so that the result gives an ascending width?  I was wondering if there was a way to treat the widths as two digit numbers and if a second digit did not exist, it would be sorted as one (i.e. 2' becomes 02' and 10' remains 10').

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: May be use a a module http://search.cpan.org/~jberger/Physics-Unit-0.04_02/lib/Physics/Unit/Scalar.pm to convert them to a common denominator and then compare?

Comment: My mind reading powers tell me that... the first of the two measurements is this "width" that you speak of and want to sort by. I am also getting a strong feeling that you want to disregard the other numbers in the string, even though you didn't actually say so.

Comment: @TLP, your assumptions are correct, except in the case of two widths that are the same with varying lengths.  For example, 2' 6'' x 10' 0'' should come after 2' 6'' x 6' 0''

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best solution to your problem is to change all imperial measures to metric.

Barring that, you can use a [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform). Simply capture and store the first two numbers in the string that corresponds to the inches and feet and use them in the sort:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @size;
$size[0] = qq#10' 0" x 14' 0":6342#;
$size[1] = qq#2' 0" x 3' 0":0#;
$size[2] = qq#4' 0" x 6' 0":829#;
$size[3] = qq#6' 0" x 9' 0":2022#;
$size[4] = qq#8' 0" x 10' 0":3145#;
$size[5] = qq#9' 0" x 12' 0":4821#;

@size = map $_->[0],
    sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] || $a->[2] <=> $b->[2] }
    map { [ $_, /^(\d+)'\s+(\d+)"/ ] } @size;

print "$_\n" for @size;
```

**Output:**

```
2' 0" x 3' 0":0
4' 0" x 6' 0":829
6' 0" x 9' 0":2022
8' 0" x 10' 0":3145
9' 0" x 12' 0":4821
10' 0" x 14' 0":6342
```

Comment: This sorts perfectly for the first two numbers (i.e. width) but is there a way to also sort by length if widths are equal?

Comment: I've updated the answer to answer my question using your method!  Thank you!